# Dual Monitors Makes Laptop Runs Slow

Tags: multiple-monitors

So I just installed ubuntu 20.04 on a laptop, and everything was working great. I noticed there was an issue when I would plug in a second monitor via HDMI, once it picked up the display and there was dual monitors, the laptop started to run very slow. Like clicking on item, it would take a while to do something, moving windows, switching between them, video on youtube slow motion, just over all slow. Once I unplugged the external monitor, everything went to working fine again, the laptop was fast again.Any ideeas, please? Thank you!

Comment: We're going to need some more information to be able to help you. First what sort of graphics card do you have in your laptop? How much RAM do you have available? How much disk space do you have available? What desktop environment are you using? Is this a standard 20.04 install?

Comment: Hi Mark, thanks for getting back to me. I have a Dell Precision M6800, 16gb ram, i7, 2.8ghzx8, 500 gb ssd, Graphics Intel Haswell mobile /Amd bonaire, and it's a standard 20.04 download from ubuntu website. I tried to download from a different website and reinstall it again, but it does the same thing. I even upgraded from 19.10 to 20.04 and again, the same story.

Comment: @Alex Any update on this? Im having a similar issue - not so slow as you described but enough to be noticeable. You any solution or workaround? Thanks

Comment: Hi Nico! No, I have no solution for this. I tried everything, in the end I decided to wait for the next release in October maybe then it will work. If you get any news how can be fixed, please let me know.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [20.04 on external monitor (2560x1600) extremely slow](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1244674/20-04-on-external-monitor-2560x1600-extremely-slow)

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar problem, and solved it using the top solution from this thread: [20.04 on external monitor (2560x1600) extremely slow](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1244674/20-04-on-external-monitor-2560x1600-extremely-slow). So this *might* be a duplicate problem (I'll let someone with a higher reputation score decide that).

Specifically, I ran `$ nvidia-settings`, went to "PRIME Profiles" and changed from "NVIDIA On-Demand" to "NVIDIA (Performance Mode)". After restarting my computer I no longer experienced any lag when using dual monitors.

See the linked thread for an image of the relevant Nvidia settings window.